# Use ports instead of domains for multiple sites

Tags: nginx

I have a server without domains, but I would like to run a few websites there. I would like to do it using ports instead of domains.

I setup a site for this port and set the application directory as a root, but now when I try to visit `http://127.0.0.1:81`, the server forwards me to `http://127.0.0.1:81/magento` and breaks my application urls. Why does nginx do it?

My config for this site is:

```
 server {
    listen 81;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/magento;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic           "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some applicatons *cough,cough,phpmyadmin,cough,cough* are weird that way. There may be an option in the application settings to provide it with a base URL it should assume (and redirect to).

Answer (score 1):

As Felix mentions in the comments above, some applications rewrite urls for you.  One way to check this would be to execute

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:81
```

and see if you get a 301/302 redirect to

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/magento
```

Nothing in this config file seems to indicate that nginx is the problem, so I would check the application itself.